# how to do select into table with clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to Clickhouse but I recall SQL having **select into** capabilities.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
INTO newtable 
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition;
```

What is the Clickhouse way to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
create table xxx_new Engine=Log as select 1 a, 2 b

DESCRIBE TABLE xxx_new

┌─name─┬─type──┬─default_type─┬─default_expression─┬─comment─┬─codec_expression─┬─ttl_expression─┐
│ a    │ UInt8 │              │                    │         │                  │                │
│ b    │ UInt8 │              │                    │         │                  │                │
└──────┴───────┴──────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘
```